# Windows 10, High contrast theme & Firefox - does not show some images

Tags: windows-10, firefox, images, svg, color-theme

When using high contrast theme on Windows 10, Firefox can use 
this setting and I find it very useful feature as I can set the background color globally.
But there are some issues with images in Firefox. Namely some images on 
some sites just disappeared. I suspect those issues are with SVG graphics only, because raster images seem to be OK everywhere.

For example SE sites now lack icons here:

[image]

Which originally was:

[image]

This is really disappointing.
Is there any solution to this problem?
I have spent some time googling this problem and rechecked some Windows 
system settings, but nothing helps. Note: I don't want to disable this feature, I like it and just want to solve the mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused because the stackexchange editor uses background images for their icons.  In high contrast mode, all background images are removed.  The only way around it would be for them to use a @media query (for high contrast) and/or instead of using a background property, use the content property.

[element]:after {content: url([image url]);} 
This alone will allow the image to show up.  It will not make it visible to all users unless the contrast ratio is high enough with the background.

.wmd-button > span**:after** {
    **content:** url("../../Img/unified/wmd-buttons.svg?v=71f92841a4f1");
    background-size: initial !important;

THe following code will work in Windows (Edge and IE11) to provide custom colored buttons that will work in high contrast (active, black-on-white, white-on-black):

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast:active){
.wmd-button > span:after {
    content: url("../../Img/unified/wmd-buttons.svg?v=71f92841a4f1");
    background-size: initial !important;
}
}